# Creating properties for iPhone items

Tags: iphone, properties, uiviewcontroller, ios6, storyboard

I am trying to write simple app for iPhone. I have storyboard populated with components, e.g. text field. Now in the  ViewController.h  I want to create properties by dragging and dropping the components from storyboard. Once you do that a pointer in the form of arrow should appear. But in my case I drag the item itself. So, what is missing? As far as I know I need to drag files somewhere in the same way as components.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to press control while dragging.

Answer (score 0):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> while dragging **not** the item as visually displayed in the Interface Builder main window, but instead the item's name in the left sidebar.

You'll need to view the `.h` file at the same time (assuming that's where you want the property to be "dragged into" the code), which you can bring up with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or by picking View > Assistant Editor > Show Assistant Editor.

Once that's showing, you can drag properties from your `.xib` into the `.h`.

Comment: Do you mean the items in the left sider under the name View Controller? Where do I need to drag them? I tried some things but no visual affect. No properties have been created too.

Comment: See edit, you need to drag the items into the header file (or wherever else you want them to live in your code)